# Tkinter dialog box with user input AND custom buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

Can't find this anywhere else on stack overflow.

I want to create a dialog box (on top of my main window) in tkinter that has message, a text input field and some custom buttons.

I know I can do

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

master = tk.Tk()
user_input = tk.simpledialog.askstring("title", "message")
```

and then take the `user_input` from there. However, how can I make the buttons have custom text and also bind them to my own functions?

Otherwise, I was thinking of making my own dialogbox class. But that's a lot of work. Is there any way I can do this natively using any of tkinter' modules?

Regards

Hugo.

Comment: If anyone knows where I can find the source code to `simpledialog.askstring`, that would be great.

Comment: ```C:\Program Files\Python3.8.6\Lib\tkinter```. You will find a file name simpledialogue.py. This is the path for python on my Machine. You should navigate to Program files > Python (version) > Lib > tkinter

Comment: @Sujay Thanks. I was just interested to see what `**kwargs` I can use.